Max Likelihood of GBM with 2 Markov States
Consider the stochastic process
$$dX_t = \mu_{\epsilon_t}X_tdt + \sigma_{\epsilon_t}X_tdW_t$$
where $W_t$ is a standard Brownian motion. The process $X_t$ is a geometric Brownian motion (GBM) whose mean and variance depend on an independent two-state Markov chain $\epsilon_t$ with state space $\{H,L\}$. The model has six parameters:

$\mu_H$: mean drift in state $H$
$\mu_L$: mean drift in state $L$
$\sigma_H$: std dev in state $H$
$\sigma_L$: std dev in state $L$
$p_H$: conditonal probability of jumping from state $L$ into state $H$
$p_L$: conditonal probability of jumping from state $H$ into state $L$

The Markov process is observable and not hidden/latent.

Question: If $X_t$ is a standard geometric Brownian motion with log-normal distribution, I know maximum likelihood estimators for $\mu$ and $\sigma$ given a time series of realizations of $X_t$. But does a GBM with regime switching also have known MLEs?

Hi: no one answered so check this out if possible. I don't know if it will help but, if not, then it may have references that might help. This paper is kind of the canonical reference on regime switching in econometrics. Unfortunately, I could only find a jstor version. https://www.jstor.org/stable/1912559?origin=crossref

This is a shorter version by the same author that's probably more of a summary on the state of regime switching but atleast it's available. https://econweb.ucsd.edu/~jhamilto/palgrav1.pdf

It's not necessary to look at Hamilton references above because I looked some more and this ( GBM with regime switching ) is quite a popular topic. Check this out for usefulness and references. https://ecommons.cornell.edu/server/api/core/bitstreams/bceed6c3-efbb-4595-ba3f-5436f9e0589c/content
